# Is there a standard name for the function $f_m(x,y) = mx + y$?

Tags: number-theory, functions, computer-science, number-systems, numerical-calculus

When formalizing the base-$m$ positional numeral system, the function $$f_m : \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$$ $$x,y \mapsto mx + y$$ is extremely useful. For example, observe that $$365 = f_{10}(f_{10}(3,6),5).$$

> **Question.** Is there an accepted name for the function $f_m$ either in general, or else in the the case $m=2$, or in the case $m = 10$, or else in the case $m=2^{64}$?

*Motivation.* I have plans to use the function $f_{2^{64}}$ in the context of a term-rewriting system that's designed to implement basic arithmetic on a standard $64$-bit computer. More generally, the idea is to specify a whole family of term-rewriting systems based on $f_m$, one for each possible value of $m$. By choosing $m := 2^n$, where $n$ is the native [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) size of the target architecture, it should be possible to obtain a system that implements arithmetic with large integers relatively efficiently, and whose correctness is extremely easy to prove (because every step involves rewriting some terms based on accepted and provably correct principles of mathematics.) To do this, I have to pick a name for this function, and I guess it's better to use the standard name if there is one.

Comment: It reminds me of the gradient intercept formula for a line.

Comment: If I am not wrong, its the equation of a line (y = mx+c), where m is the slope and c is the point at which the line intersects y or x axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inverse of the function you gave $$f_m: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$$ $$a \mapsto (b,r) \backepsilon a=bm + r $$
is called Euclidean division so logically your function should be called Euclidean multiplication.  Though i've never heard that term used.

Comment: Very nice insight! Write $\mathrm{ediv}_m$ for euclidean division by $m$, which is defined by asserting that $\mathrm{ediv}_m(z)$ is the unique pair $(x,y)$ such that $mx+y = z$ and $y \in \{0,\ldots,m-1\}.$ Also, write $\mathrm{emult}_m$ for the function defined by $\mathrm{emult}_m(x,y) = mx + y$. Then we do indeed have $\mathrm{emult} \circ \mathrm{ediv} = \mathrm{id}_\mathbb{N},$ suggesting that "Euclidean multiplication" is a left-inverse of "Euclidean division".

Answer (score 1):

I would call it
"MiXkeY mouse".

Comment: But as you implicitly recognize, there is no standard name.

Comment: I like "MixkeY mouse."  But $mx+y$ is also a "linear function" of $(x,y)$.

Comment: @Michael:  $mx+y$ is indeed a linear function of $x$ and $y$, but not the only one